# xdvi - is the "margins" option working?

Tags: dvi, xdvi

I'm using xdvi with a shrink factor of 2 (`xdvi -s 2`).

From the xdvi man pages:"-margins (.Margin)  Specifies  the  size  of  both  the  top margin and side margin.  This determines the ``home'' position of the page within the window as follows.  If the entire page fits in the window, then the margin settings are ignored.  **If, even after removing the margins from  the  left, right,  top,  and  bottom,  the page still cannot fit in the window, then the page is put in the           window such that the top and left margins are hidden, and presumably the upper left-hand  corner of  the  text  on  the page will be in the upper left-hand corner of the window**.  Otherwise, the text is centered in the window.  The dimension should be a decimal number optionally followed by any of the two-letter abbreviations for units accepted by TeX (pt, pc, in, bp, cm, mm,  dd,  cc, or  sp)"

With a shrink factor 2 the document doesn't fit in the window so I tried `xdvi -margins 4 -s 2` but no change. Trying other ooptions like -margins 2cm or -margins 2 cm or -margins "2 cm" etc had no effect either.

Is the `-margins` option working? I also tried -`sidemargin` and - `topmargin` with no results either.

Thanks